# nokogiri not recognising classes with hyphens

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.priceangels.com/site-map.html"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.css('.lav1').each do |item|
  puts item.text
end
doc.css('.masonry-brick').each do |item|
  puts item.text
end
```

This is my first time using nokogiri. The first each loop behaves as expected. The second each loop fails to find any matches.
Does Nokogiri not recognise class names with dashes (hyphens)?
How do I get nokogiri to find the '.masonry-brick' classes?

Comment: this class does not exist at the file you're looking at.

Comment: The elements in that class are probably added with javascript — they are not in the original HTML.

Comment: Thanks. I was following a tutorial and used selectorgadget to identify the the class. I didn't think about classes being added by javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 doc.css("ul.sitemap-item a").each do |me|
     puts me.text
 end
```

Is this what you were looking for?

also

```
<div class="hello world"> 
doc.css("div[@class='hello world']")
```

You can use that if you're having problems with spaces.

Comment: Thanks. "ul.sitemap-item" is what I need.